# Get User ID from username Instagram

Tags: php, jquery, json, instagram

I am trying to find out how can I get a user ID from a username using Instagram API but I have no luck..

My code so far is:

```
$username = 'some user name';
$username = strtolower($username); // sanitization
$token = "ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE";
$url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=".$username."&access_token=".$token;
$get = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($get);

foreach($json->data as $user)
{
    if($user->username == $username)
    {
        return $user->id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to URL encode the `$username`? Note that spaces will break the `$url`. Try using `rawurlencode()` around your `$url`

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you getting any data in `$get`? Can you echo it?

Comment: Try using `http_build_query` to build your query string.  `$query = http_build_query(array('username'=>$username,'access_token'=>$token));  $url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?{$query}";`

Answer (score 0):

Using the suggestions from the comments, I was able to get the userid from username using this code. Please let me know as I am not the greatest PHP developer and there might be a more concise way of doing this.

```
$user = USER_NAME;
$count = NUMBER_TO_RETURN;
$token = ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE;

$query = http_build_query(
                array(
                    'q'=>$user,
                    'count'=>$count,
                    'access_token'=>$token

                )
            );  
    $url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?{$query}";

    // Gets our data
    function fetchData($url){
         $ch = curl_init();
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
         $result = curl_exec($ch);
         curl_close($ch); 
         return $result;
    }

    // Pulls and parses data.
    $result = fetchData($url);
    $result = json_decode($result);
    $userid = $result->data[0]->id;
echo $userid;
```

Comment: This approach won't work for short usernames. For example, for this user -  https://instagram.com/mus, you will get all kind of users which are matching "mus" - "mussiemu", "musclekingz", "mustafaseven", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Put username in "", for example:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=%22bordeux1%22&access_token=TOKEN

For me works fine.